# how to regex a string between two tokens in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Asked many times, but I can't get it to work...

I have strings like:

```
"text!../tmp/widgets/tmp_widget_header.html"
```

and am trying like this to extract `widget_header`:

```
var temps[i] = "text!../tmp/widgets/tmp_widget_header.html";
var thisString = temps[i].regexp(/.*tmp_$.*\.*/) )
```

but that does not work.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you expecting the `$` to do in your regex?

Comment: It's where I want to start extracting the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var s = "text!../tmp/widgets/tmp_widget_header.html",
    re = /\/tmp_([^.]+)\./;

var match = re.exec(s);

if (match)
    alert(match[1]);
```

This will match:

- a `/` character
- the characters `tmp_`
- one or more of any character that is not the `.` character. These are captured.
- a `.` character

If a match was found, it will be at index `1` of the resulting Array.

Comment: almost. If I have `text!../tmp/page/tmp_page_footer.html` then I'm getting back `["/tmp_page_footer." , "page_footer"]. Any idea why?

Comment: @frequent: Isn't that the result you want? The targeted text `"page_footer"` is at index `[1]` of the resulting Array.

Comment: @frequent: Just be sure to test to see if there was a match before trying to access the index. If there was no match, you get `null` instead of an empty Array, so trying to access an index on `null` will throw an error.

Answer (score 3):

This prints `widget_header`:

```
var s = "text!../tmp/widgets/tmp_widget_header.html";
var matches = s.match(/tmp_(.*?)\.html/);
console.log(matches[1]);
```

Comment: also thanks. I go with the other answer, cause it was faster.

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
var temps[i] = "text!../tmp/widgets/tmp_widget_header.html";
var thisString = temps[i].regexp(/.*tmp_$.*\.*/) )
```

You are saying:

"Match any string that starts with any number of any characters, followed by "tmp_", followed by the end of input, followed by any number of periods."

```
.*   : Any number of any character (except newline)
tmp_ : Literally "tmp_" 
$    : End of input/newline - this will never be true in this position
\.   : " . ", a period
\.*  : Any number of periods
```

Plus when using the regex() function you need to pass a string, using string notation like `var re = new RegExp("ab+c")` or `var re = new RegExp('ab+c')` not in regex notation using slash. You also have either an extra, or missing parenthesis, and no characters are actually being captured.

What you want to do is:

"Find a string that preceded by the begining of input, followed by one or more of any character, followed by "tmp_"; followed by a single period, followed by one or more of any character, followed by the end of input;t that contains one or more of any character. Capture that string."

So:

```
var string = "text!../tmp/widgets/tmp_widget_header.html";
var re = /^.+tmp_(.+)\..+$/; //I use the simpler slash notation

var out = re.exec(string);   //execute the regex

console.log(out[1]);         //Note that out is an array, the first (here only) catpture sting is at index 1
```

This regex `/^.+tmp_(.+)\..+$/` means:

```
^    : Match beginning of input/line
.+   : One or more of any character (except newline), "+" is one or more
tmp_ : Constant "tmp_"
\.   : A single period
.+   : As above
$    : End of input/line
```

You could also use this as `RegEx('^.+tmp_(.+)\..+$');` not that when we use `RegEx();` we do not have the slash marks, instead we use quote marks (single or double will work), to pass it as a string.

Now this would also match `var string = "Q%$#^%$^%$^%$^43etmp_ebeb.45t4t#$^g"` and `out == 'ebeb'`. So depending on the specific use you may wish to replace any " . " used to signify **any** character (except newline) with bracketed "[ ]" character lists, as this may filter out unwanted results. You milage may vary.

For more information visit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions